# Apply conditional formatting to any cell in Col A that matches the value of any cell in the range B3:B11

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In google sheets, I would like to apply conditional formatting to any cell in Col A that matches the value of any cell in  the range B3:B11  See sample image.

[image: sample conditional formatting I'm trying to achieve]

I tried "custom formula is": =A3=B3:B11  over the range A3:A11, but that created unexpected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both text or numbers you can use this:

```
=SUM(--ARRAYFORMULA(OR(A1=$B$3:$B$11)*(A1<>"")))
```

Comment: This solved it.  As it happens I wrote a poor example, I do have both numbers and text in my sheet and should have noted that above in my example.  I didn't think about how that might impact the needed formula.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try on range A3:A:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A3&""; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; B$3:B))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for exact word match(*skips partial matches*)

`=REGEXMATCH(A1, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B:B,"(.+)","\\b$1\\b"))))`

-

[image]

Comment: I wrote a poor example, I do have both numbers and text in my actual sheet and should have noted that above in my example.  I didn't think about how that might impact the needed formula.  Thanks for your help.